# django 1.6: create slug url

Tags: python, django, django-urls, slug

I have a clinic model and currently their links look like this

```
localhost:8000/clinic/1/
```

I want to make them look like this

```
localhost:8000/clinic/Nice-Medical-Clinic/
```

I want the slug to be the name of the clinic

Here is the models.py

```
class Clinic(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    email = models.EmailField(blank = True, null = True)
    address = map_fields.AddressField(max_length=200
    website = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank = True, null = True)
    submitted_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null = True, blank = True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
      from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
      return reverse('meddy1.views.clinicProfile', args=[str(self.id)])
```

Here is the views.py

```
def clinicProfile(request, slug, id):
    clinic = Clinic.objects.get(id=id)
    doctors = Doctor.objects.all().order_by('-netlikes')

    d = getVariables()

    d.update({'clinic': clinic, 'doctors': doctors, })
    return render(request, 'meddy1/clinicprofile.html', d)
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^clinic/(?P<id>\d+)/$', views.clinicProfile, name='clinicProfile'),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a [Slugfield](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#slugfield) or a CharField to your model, and populate it when ever you create or edit your model.

```
class Clinic(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    ...
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=200)



    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.name, instance=self)
        super(Clinic, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

**Edit:**

If you have your url defined like @Norman8054 said:

```
url(r'^clinic/(?P<slug>\w+)/$', views.clinicProfile, name='clinicProfile'),
```

You can get the object in your views:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def clinicProfile(request, slug):
    clinic = Clinic.objects.get(slug=slug)
```

Those are the basic steps. If you want to be sure the slug field is unic, you need to add some validation to the save method, or slugify with another field of the model. If you think that the slug field may change, you probably need to add the id of the object to the url as well. But those are use-case based decisions.

Comment: Thanks @cor. This will only work for the new clinics I add. What about the existing clinics? How can i make the existing clinics to have a slug as the clinic name ?

Comment: I don't know the best way for that. I would do it manually from shell. Once you have made the changes and migrated de db,  something like: `clinics = Clinic.objects.all()` and then `for clinic in clinics: clinic.slug = slugify(clinic.name,instance=clinic)`

Comment: It's actually easier than that. `clinics = Clinic.objects.all()` and then `for clinic in clinics: clinic.save()`. Also keep in mind that the names of the clinics have to be unique. You can't map the same urls to two different clinics.

Comment: Thanks @cor. Could you please elaborate on how to get the object by it's slug in views. I'm very new to django

Answer (score 0):

Just to extend cor's answer: Use a [named group](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/urls/#named-groups) in your urls.py:

```
url(r'^clinic/(?P<slug>\w+)/$', views.clinicProfile, name='clinicProfile'),
```